# Is snapshot.ref equivalent to firestore.collection('snapshotCollection').doc(snapshot.id)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I want to get a firebase document reference to use it in a filter for another query:

```
.where('project', '==', projectDocRef)
```

to get the project reference is equivalent to do:

```
projectDocRef = snapshot.ref;
```

and

```
proyectDocRef = firestore.collection('projectcolection').doc(snapshot.id);
```

?

Does any of the alternatives have any advantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, 1st method can be used only when you've fetched the document already and have its DocumentSnapshot. Using  ref would convenient here.

When you don't have a DocumentSnapshot, then you would have to use .doc() to get a DocumentReference.

You can remove .collection() just yo reduce some code like:

```
proyectDocRef = firestore.doc('projectcolection/docID')
```

Comment: Yes, in both cases I have fetched the document with a previous query. I have a list of documents and loop through them. So in this case snapshot.ref would be better?

Comment: @IteraConsultoríaPYMES I would say yes, you don't have to create another object with `doc()`. But if it's easier to use `doc()` rather than fetching the snapshot somewhere deep from the state, then use that.